# In Hadoop what is stored in dfs.data.dir (in hdfs-site.xml parameter) & the director we create using dfs -mkdir

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I created a directory as below and create hive table using below syntax

a) 
1) dfs -mkdir /app/hadoop/warehouse/

2) Create table employee ( empid int, name string , surname string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ‘,’
location ‘/app/hadoop/warehouse/’;

3) load data inpath ‘/input file location .txt’
overwrite into table employee;

if my understanding is correct , all the blocks are stored under /app/hadoop/warehouse/ directory. Please confirm ?

---

b) what is the purpose of dfs.data.dir parameter in hdfs-site.xml , for the directories we mention here?

---

c) What ever the directory  we create as the part of step a) should be mentioned in Step b) ?

I appreciate , for your clarification

Thanks
Naveen

Answer (score 2):

1) Check the Apache documentation [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hdfs-default.html) for more details on dfs.data.dir and other properties.

2) File system is an abstraction of raw data, so the blocks are not stored in the /app/hadoop/warehouse/ folder. The blocks are stored in the DN's as specified by the dfs.data.dir property in the hdfs-site.xml.

3) In Hive the logical table should be associated with the data in HDFS. So, the folder name in HDFS should be specified while creating the table.